# Is this big O notation correct for this c++ code?

Tags: c++, big-o

currently I have best case as o(n), worst case as o(n). I am unsure if this is correct for the following code segment and I would really appreciate if someone could confirm it is correct, or explain why it's wrong. Thanks!

```
template<typename T>
void vector_print(const T& vector, bool repeat)
{
    for (typename T::size_type i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (typename T::size_type j = 0; j < vector.size(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << vector[j] << ",";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        if (!repeat) {
            break;
        }
        repeat = !repeat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain your reasoning

Comment: Are we taking about time or space complexity?

Comment: Also, why is the outer loop written so counter intuitively?

Comment: Reasoning is that the outer loop will never be executed twice. Therefore it's O(2*vector.size()) so O(n). Just like Bill said.

Comment: I understand what it does, but why phrase it so awkwardly?

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is never going to be executed more than twice, so you've got `O(2*vector.size())`, which reduces to `O(vector.size())`.

So your answer seems correct to me.