# Sum of recursive vector time complexity

Tags: c++, big-o

The time complexities I have are, best case: o(1), worst case: o(n). Is this correct?

```
int recursive_vector_sum(const int& vector, int min, int max) {
    
    if(min > max) return 0;

    int mid = ((max - min) / 2) + min;
    int result = vector[mid];
    result += recursive_vector_sum(vector, min, mid - 1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is this a series of assignments you're solving? You've already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067167). And as before, you have not explained why you think your solution is correct. Also, why are you deleting questions when you receive an answer?

Comment: Yeah, also I have explained. and I can keep the post up, I used it to get clarification which I got

Comment: I don't see any explanation in either of your posts. Why do you think the bounds are o(1) or o(n)? And the questions and answers are not just for your benefit, they are for everyone. Please undelete all your questions that have received answers.

Comment: @HartMekas edits of question should improve it, not make it useless. I've rollback your changes which can be considered a vandalism.

Comment: I have downvoted for your deletion of a prior question that also removed a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is O(n) period.  You do one `vector[i]` for each `i`.

The recursive portion simply means that the recursive depth is lg(n).